# Finding text within a Span and displaying in an alert

Tags: jquery

On my current page I currently have a span which is rendered within an iframe:

```
<span id="SpanID_ctrlHelp_lblHelp">HelpText</span>
```

With the below code I am able to display 'HelpText' within an alert:

```
$('div[id*="MyControl"]').find("[id*='_fraDefaultFrame']")
                         .contents()
                         .each(function () {
    var txtBox = $('#SpanID_ctrlHelp_lblHelp').html();
    alert(txtBox);
});
```

The above code works well however I would like to activate an alert for every instance of help text on a given screen.
Note all available help text has a span ID which contains the following "_ctrlHelp_lblHelp"

Hope someone can make sense of this and assist...

Comment: are you talking about alerting multiple times? or combining their text and alerting once?

Comment: SO there will be many spans with the same ID="SpanID_ctrlHelp_lblHelp" ? and you want alert for all of therm

Comment: Alerting multiple times i.e. if there are 3 lots of help text for 3 different fields I would like to display 3 individual alerts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do:

```
var txtBox = $('[id$="_ctrlHelp_lblHelp"]').html(); // id ends by
```

or this:

```
var txtBox = $('[id*="_ctrlHelp_lblHelp"]').html(); // id contains
```

---

Or you may try this:

```
 $('[id$="_ctrlHelp_lblHelp"]').each(function(){
     alert(this.innerHTML);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('span[id$="_ctrlHelp_lblHelp"]').each(function(){
     alert($(this).html());
});
```

OR

```
$('span[id*="_ctrlHelp_lblHelp"]').each(function(){
     alert($(this).html());
});
```